# Add dynamic FormControl Validators without removing old ones

Tags: angular, forms, validation, angular-validation

I have a form like below

```
this.personForm = new FormGroup({
            title: new FormControl(this.person.salutation, Validators.compose([
            Validators.minLength(2)
        ])),
            firstName: new FormControl(this.person.firstName, Validators.compose([
            Validators.minLength(4)
        ])),
});
```

Based on a configuration from an API call I want to make them dynamically required or not. I  know I can use `formControl.setValidators([Validators.required])` but that will clear existing Validators.

I was hoping to achieve it in one of the following ways

- A function for just adding (Exp: `addValidators([])`)
- **OR** a function that would give me the list of Validators a formControl already has, so that I can join them with what I want to add. (Exp: `getValidators()`)

**Unfortunately**(as for as I know) none of above 2 functions exist. So how can one add a new Validation to a formControl without having to know already existing ones?

Comment: Can you please share your server validation json

Comment: @AjayOjha this is all front-end, what server validation do you mean? The API will just give me an array of booleans that will let me know whether to make formControls required or not. The rest is all Front-End

Comment: I thought dynamic rules are coming from server,  now understood, based on which condition you want to apply required?

Comment: @AjayOjha That part is just business logic, don't get confused with that. For simplicity consider just this: how can I add an additional Validation to `title` after form is inited but without losing old Validations (In this case Validator.minLength(2))?. Thanks

Comment: please refer this provided link for conditionally required validation https://rxweb.io/validation-validators/required#conditionalexpression and please let me if this doesn't fulfil your need.

Comment: I supouse you can use "setValidators"  https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#setvalidators. As you can send as argument an array of validators, some like "control.setValidator([control.validator,newValidator])" or validators[]=control.validator; validators.push(newValidator) maybe make the trick

Comment: @Eliseo yes I can always do that but it requires to save all validations somewhere in a variable and apply them again together with required once required flags are retrieved from API. I was hoping for a much cleaner solution, by defining the Form once and then only applying Validators.required but I guess that is not possible currently in Reactive Forms

Answer (score 2):

I supouse you can use a customValidator that depends of one variable, In the example, a button make a variable "yet" true or false. depending the form is valid or not

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template:`
  <form [formGroup]="personForm">
     <input formControlName="title"/>
     <input formControlName="firstName"/>
  </form>
  <button (click)="addValidator()">click</button>
  <hr/>
  {{personForm?.errors|json}}
  {{personForm?.valid}}`
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  yet: boolean;
  personForm: FormGroup;
  person = { salutation: "", firstName: "" }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.personForm = new FormGroup({
      title: new FormControl(this.person.salutation, Validators.compose([
        Validators.maxLength(2)
      ])),
      firstName: new FormControl(this.person.firstName, Validators.compose([
        Validators.minLength(4)
      ])),
    }, this.customValidator())
  }
  addValidator() {
    this.yet = !this.yet;
    this.personForm.updateValueAndValidity();
  }
  customValidator() {
    return (group: FormGroup) => {
      if (!this.yet)
        return null;
      if (group.get('title').value == '')
        return { title: 'required' }
    }
  }
```

see [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5kvhfr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Interesting Idea, will try it out. Thanks!